# php preg_match_all need multiple results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to have `preg_match_all` to return all the patterns it finds even if results have already been used.  The below example isolates the issue.

```
$str = "whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 ll";
$pattern = '/.{0,100}\D[aaa]{3}\D{1}[0-9]{5}\D{1}/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $amatches);
var_dump($amatches);
```

The results for above returns one array element.

```
0=>    `whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 `
```

What I want is 2 array elements.

```
0=>    `whatever aaa 34567`   
1=>    `whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to do the job.

- Look for strings matching "any characters followed by (and including) three 'a' characters, some space and five digits". There may be trailing spaces. The `\b` denotes a word boundary, preventing matches on "xaaa 12345", "aaa 123456" or "aaa 12345xyz"
- Concatenate the matching string to `$soFar`, which contains any previously matched strings
- Append that string to the `$result` array

I am not quite sure whether you wanted the "foo"s and "bar"s to remain in the string so I just left them in.

```
$str = "whatever foo aaa 12345 bar aaa 34567 aaa 56789 baz fez";

preg_replace_callback(
    '/.*?\baaa +\d{5}\b\s*/',
    function ($matches) use (&$result, &$soFar) {
        $soFar .= $matches[0];
        $result[] = trim($soFar);
    }, $str
);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => whatever foo aaa 12345 
    [1] => whatever foo aaa 12345 bar aaa 34567 
    [2] => whatever foo aaa 12345 bar aaa 34567 aaa 56789 
)
```

Two-step version using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
preg_match_all('/.*?\baaa +\d{5}\b\s*/', $str, $matches);
$matches = array_map(
    function ($match) use (&$soFar) {
        $soFar .= $match;
        return trim($soFar);
    },
    $matches[0]
);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks mhall that is exactly what I needed.  I tinkered with your solution a bit to get to exactly what I needed. $pattern = '/.{0,7}\baaa\W{1,3}\d{5}\b\s*/i';  which will allow for the following string to appear 3 times.  $str = "whatever foo -aaa, 12345 foo aaa, 34567 aaa, 56789 baz fez";

Answer (score 0):

this is a little closer:

```
$str = "whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 ll";
$pattern = '/^((.*)\D[aaa]{3}\D{1}[0-9]{5}\D{1})?/';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $amatches);
var_dump($amatches);
```

returns

```
 array(3) { 
        [0] => string(29) "whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 " 
        [1] => string(29) "whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 " 
        [2] => string(18) "whatever aaa 34567" 
    }
```

or this uses preg_match_all still:

```
$str = "whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 ll";
$pattern = '/^((.*)\D[aaa]{3}\D{1}[0-9]{5}\D{1})?/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $amatches);
var_dump($amatches);
```

I think that what is happening is your .{0,100} is being read through the whole thing without allowing the regex to kick in at the end at all. The ? Makes sure that it ends with your pattern.

Comment: Thanks dgig,   It kind of works, however if I extend it as shown below there should now be 3 separate array elements it does not extend.   
I also need the pattern to cap the value at the beginning because it is readying from a file.  
$str = "whever1 aaa 12345 xx whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 ll";  
Result   
  0 => string 'whever1 aaa 12345 xx whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 '   
  1 => string 'whever1 aaa 12345 xx whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 '   
  2 => string 'whever1 aaa 12345 xx whatever aaa 34567' (length=39)

Comment: I'm not sure, but this is a site that you can test your regex's with, it has really helped me learn a lot: https://regex101.com/

Comment: what about this? $pattern = '/[aaa]{3} [0-9]{5}/';

Comment: Thanks dgig,  $pattern = '/\D[aaa]{3}\D{1}[0-9]{5}\D/' will bring up 3 results with $str = "whever1 aaa 12345 xx whatever aaa 34567   aaa 56789 ll"  it will only bring up 2 results with $str = "whever1 aaa 12345 xx whatever aaa 34567 aaa 56789 ll"  This is due to an extra space between 34567 and aaa.   So the question remains how to bring up all results independent of what was found.  -- Glenn